# Why can't I specified the dependency version in a private pod?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a private pod and some configuration of the podspec file is as follows:

`s.dependency 'QMUIKit','~> 2.7.1'`

> By the way, the newest version of QMUIKit is `2.7.2`.And the cocoapods version of mine is `1.4.0`

When I use `pod lib lint` command to verify the podspec file,I found that `QMUIKit` is installing to `2.7.2`,the newest version in the master repo of cocoapods. And it is for this reason that my private pod can't be validated.

Why is that?What's wrong with the profile.

Comment: Would it be possible to post the validation error as reported by the `pod lib lint`?

Comment: @Alladinian Some methods have been changed between version 2.7.1 and 2.7.2 in QMUIKit. I need 2.7.1 and also has already specified the version to 2.7.1 in the podspec file of my private pod.  My english is bad,sorry.

Comment: If you need version `2.7.1` and _only_ this, then you'll have to change your dependency to `s.dependency 'QMUIKit','2.7.1'` (that is, without the `~>` operator)